# Edit existing Image in a JFrame

Tags: java, image, swing, edit

I am able to do free hand Drawing in a frame and I am able to save it as .png.

I want to load the same image in a `JFrame` and I should edit the same image with free hand drawing. Is it possible?

I am using to draw this sentence:

```
 graphics2D.drawLine(oldX, oldY, currentX, currentY);
```

But I could not edit the image after loading it in the JFrame.

To load the image I've used:

```
 Graphics g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
```

Comment: *"Is it possible?"* Yes - see [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for more details

Answer (score 1):

*"Is it possible?"* Yes - see [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for more details.

Instead of painting to the `Graphics` context of the component, you'll need to paint to the image's using `BufferedImage#createGraphics`

You can take a look at [Drawing an Image](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/drawimage.html) and [Working with Images](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/index.html) for more details

Comment: Can any one suggest a reason for the downvote?  Does this not provide enough information to answer the OPs question...without going to the point of providing a fully runnable example?